# Explode Funciton not working in PHP Shows error line expects parameter 2

Tags: php

here is `$_POST['members']` and I want to explode it with `|`

```
[members] => Array
        (
            [0] => test.com|test Melissa
            [1] => eboo@abcd.com.au|Buckley test
            [2] => testtest@test.com.au|test Ashley
            [3] => testset.com.au|Forno test
            [4] => get.com.au|test Nathan
            [5] =>set.com.au|Brown test
        )
```

I am trying with follows php code

```
$get=explode('|',$_POST['members']);
echo '<pre>'; 
print_r($get);
```

Comment: you need to loop through the `$_POST['members']` array and explode it

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
foreach($_POST['members'] as $str){
  $get[] = explode('|',$str);
}
print_r($get);
```

Answer (score 0):

as `$_POST['members']` is array, you need to use explode in foreach by accessing all array elements:

```
foreach($_POST['members'] as $members)
{
    $get=explode('|',$members);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($get);
}
```

Comment: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($get);` should be outside the loop

Comment: @Lemon OP has not mentioned he want to create single array for all explode result...everyone will post answer as per his/her own understanding in this situation...

Answer (score 0):

Loop Through the Data Array, store the result of your Explode in a new Array and perhaps you got what you want like so:

```
<?php
    $arr                    = [
        0 => "test.com|test Melissa",
        1 => "eboo@abcd.com.au|Buckley test",
        2 => "testtest@test.com.au|test Ashley",
        3 => "testset.com.au|Forno test",
        4 => "get.com.au|test Nathan",
        5 => "set.com.au|Brown test"
    ];

        $arrSubData         = array();
        foreach($arr as $pipeDividedString){
            $arrSubData[]   = explode('|', $pipeDividedString);
        }


        var_dump($arrSubData);
```

**DUMPS**

```
    array (size=6)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              0 => string 'test.com' (length=8)
              1 => string 'test Melissa' (length=12)
          1 => 
            array (size=2)
              0 => string 'eboo@abcd.com.au' (length=16)
              1 => string 'Buckley test' (length=12)
          2 => 
            array (size=2)
              0 => string 'testtest@test.com.au' (length=20)
              1 => string 'test Ashley' (length=11)
          3 => 
            array (size=2)
              0 => string 'testset.com.au' (length=14)
              1 => string 'Forno test' (length=10)
          4 => 
            array (size=2)
              0 => string 'get.com.au' (length=10)
              1 => string 'test Nathan' (length=11)
          5 => 
            array (size=2)
              0 => string 'set.com.au' (length=10)
              1 => string 'Brown test' (length=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['members']` is an array and `explode();` works on strings.  You'll have to loop through the array and explode each value.  Something like this :

```
$arr = array(
  'test.com|test Melissa',
  'eboo@abcd.com.au|Buckley test',
  'testtest@test.com.au|test Ashley',
  'testset.com.au|Forno test',
  'get.com.au|test Nathan',
  'set.com.au|Brown test'
);
$get = array();
foreach ($_POST['members'] as $member) {
  $get[] = explode('|',$member);
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($get);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to `explode` the values you need to loop trough `$_POST['members']`, for that you can use [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).
The following, is an example that uses [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) :

```
<?php
$members = !empty($_POST['members']) ? $_POST['members'] : die("post members is empty");
foreach($members as $member)
{
    list($siteEmail, $name) = explode("|", $member);
    echo "<pre> $siteEmail $name </pre>";
}
```

---

http://ideone.com/qdDmSe

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

`foreach($_POST['members'] as $val){
    $get = explode('|',$val);

}
 echo "<pre>";print_r($get);`